# Running statistics on multiple lines in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple HTTP headers in one giant file, separated with one empty line.

```
Host
Connection
Accept
From
User-Agent
Accept-Encoding

Host
Connection
Accept
From
User-Agent
Accept-Encoding
X-Forwarded-For

cookie
Cache-Control
referer
x-fb-sim-hni
Host
Accept
user-agent
x-fb-net-sid
x-fb-net-hni
X-Purpose
accept-encoding
x-fb-http-engine
Connection

User-Agent
Host
Connection
Accept-Encoding
```

I have approximately 10,000,000 of headers separated with an empty line. 
If I want to discover trends, like header order, I want to do aggregate headers to a one-liner (how I can aggregate lines ending with an empty line and do that separately for all headers?):

Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding

and follow with: `uniq -c|sort -nk1,`
so I could receive:

```
197897 Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
8732233 User-Agent,Host,Connection,Accept-Encoding
```

What would be the best approach and most effective one to parse that massive file and get that data?

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Do if the lines in the block are in a different order, is that unique?

Comment: This is used for header order classification to determine some top used combinations. For example, Chrome uses different header order than Mozilla. So you you gather massive sample of HTTP request headers, you can have a sense of commonly used header combinations, and this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is `User-Agent,Host` the same as `Host,User-Agent` for example? would that be `1  User-Agent,Host; 1 Host,User-Agent` or `2 Host,User-Agent`?

Comment: I saw that the data I am gathering is corrupted at some point (containing GET requests with payload, that skews the couting). Yes, it is different. For example Firefox uses following header order: Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Content-Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your your `1.5milGETs.txt` file (and converting the triple `\n\n\n` to `\n\n` to separate blocks) you can use `ruby` in paragraph mode:

```
$ ruby -F'\n' -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new(0); $/=""
                                       def commafy(n)
                                             n.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,"\\&,").reverse
                                         end
                                         }
                                         h[$F.join(",")]+=1
                                        # p $_
                              END{ printf "Total blocks: %s\n", commafy(h.values.sum)
                                      h2=h.sort_by {|k,v| -v}
                                      h2[0..10].map {|k,v| printf "%10s %s\n", commafy(v), k}
                                      }' 1.5milGETs.txt
```

That prints the total number of blocks, sorts them large->small, prints the top 10.

Prints:

```
Total blocks: 1,262,522
    71,639 Host,Accept,User-Agent,Pragma,Connection
    70,975 Host,ros-SecurityFlags,ros-SessionTicket,ros-Challenge,ros-HeadersHmac,Scs-Ticket,If-Modified-Since,User-Agent
    40,781 Host,Accept,User-Agent,Pragma,nnCoection,Connection,X-Forwarded-For
    35,485 Accept,ros-SecurityFlags,ros-SessionTicket,ros-Challenge,ros-HeadersHmac,Scs-Ticket,If-Modified-Since,User-Agent,Accept-Language,UA-CPU,Accept-Encoding,Host,Connection
    34,005 User-Agent,Host,Connection,Accept-Encoding
    30,668 Host,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding,Connection
    25,547 Host,Accept,Accept-Language,Connection,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    22,581 Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Encoding
    19,311 Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
    14,694 Host,Connection,User-Agent,Accept,Referer,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cookie
    12,290 Host,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
```

That takes about 8 seconds on a 6 year old Mac.

Awk will be 3x faster and entirely appropriate for this job.

Ruby will give you more output options and easier analysis of the data. You can create an interactive HTML documents; output JSON, quoted csv, xml trivially; interact with a database; invert keys and values in a statement; filter; etc.

Comment: @EdMorton : Let me clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for sorted_in, all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="," }
{ $1=$1; cnt[$0]++ }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (rec in cnt) {
        print cnt[rec] " " rec
    }
}
```

After running `dos2unix` on the sample you posted (1.5milGETs.txt):

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk 1.5milGETs.txt > ou.awk

real    0m4.898s
user    0m4.758s
sys     0m0.108s


$ head -10 ou.awk
71639 Host,Accept,User-Agent,Pragma,Connection
70975 Host,ros-SecurityFlags,ros-SessionTicket,ros-Challenge,ros-HeadersHmac,Scs-Ticket,If-Modified-Since,User-Agent
40781 Host,Accept,User-Agent,Pragma,nnCoection,Connection,X-Forwarded-For
35485 Accept,ros-SecurityFlags,ros-SessionTicket,ros-Challenge,ros-HeadersHmac,Scs-Ticket,If-Modified-Since,User-Agent,Accept-Language,UA-CPU,Accept-Encoding,Host,Connection
34005 User-Agent,Host,Connection,Accept-Encoding
30668 Host,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding,Connection
25547 Host,Accept,Accept-Language,Connection,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
22581 Host,User-Agent,Accept,Accept-Encoding
19311 Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
14694 Host,Connection,User-Agent,Accept,Referer,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cookie
```

Comment: input shared in the comment above.

Comment: I learn more awk every time I read one of your posts.  While some optimized C++ thingy on a parallel supercomputer might be faster, this is plenty fast and only took a few minutes to write. Well done.

Comment: s/minutes/seconds :-). btw I notice our 2 answers do not produce the same output. idk if the OP changed inputs between you taking your snapshot and me taking mine but if not one of us has a bug!

Comment: I had a bug. `ruby -00` vs  `$/=""` Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer written in (POSIX) C, which AFAICT does what OP wants. The C solution seems to be faster than an AWK based solution. That may or may not be useful, it all depends on how frequent the program is run and the input data.

The main takeaway:

- The program memory maps the input file and alters the mapped copy.
- It replaces newline characters with commas where appropriate, and
  newlines with nul characters to separate each entry in the input
  file. IOW, foo\nbar\n\nbaz\n becomes foo,bar\0baz\0.
- The program also builds a table of entries, which is just an array of
  char-pointers into the memory mapped file.
- The program sorts the entries using standard string functions, but only moves the pointers values, not the actual data
- Then the program creates a new array of unique entries and counts how many instances there are for each string. (This part can probably be made a bit faster)
- The array of unique entries is then sorted in descending order
- Finally, the program prints the contents of the unique array

Anyway, here's the code. (disclaimer: It's written to be postable here on SO)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct uniq {
    char *val;
    size_t count;
};

struct entry {
    char *val;
};

// Some globals
size_t g_filesize;
char*  g_baseaddr;

struct entry *g_entries;
size_t g_entrysize, g_entrycapacity;

struct uniq *g_unique;
size_t g_uniquesize, g_uniquecapacity;

static inline void mapfile(const char *filename)
{
    int fd;
    struct stat st;

    if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1 || fstat(fd, &st)) {
        perror(filename);
        exit(__LINE__);
    }

    g_baseaddr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (g_baseaddr == (void *)MAP_FAILED) {
        perror(filename);
        close(fd);
        exit(__LINE__);
    }

    close(fd);
    g_filesize = st.st_size;
}

// Guestimate how many entries we have. We do this only to avoid early
// reallocs, so this isn't that important. Let's say 100 bytes per entry.
static inline void setup_entry_table(void)
{
    g_entrycapacity = g_filesize / 100; 
    g_entrysize = 0;

    size_t cb = sizeof *g_entries * g_entrycapacity;
    if ((g_entries = malloc(cb)) == NULL)
        exit(__LINE__);

    memset(g_entries, 0, cb);
}

static inline void realloc_if_needed(void)
{
    if (g_entrysize == g_entrycapacity) {
        size_t newcap = g_entrycapacity * 2;
        size_t cb = newcap * sizeof *g_entries;

        struct entry *tmp = realloc(g_entries, cb);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            exit(__LINE__);

        g_entries = tmp;
        g_entrycapacity = newcap;
    }
}

static inline void add_entry(char *p)
{
    realloc_if_needed();
    g_entries[g_entrysize].val = p;
    g_entrysize++;
}

// Convert input data to proper entries by replacing \n with either
// ',' or \0. We add \0 to separate the entries.
static inline void convert_to_entries(void)
{
    char *endaddr = g_baseaddr + g_filesize;
    char *prev, *s = g_baseaddr;

    // First entry
    prev = s;

    while(s < endaddr) {
        char *nl = strchr(s, '\n');
        if (nl == s) {
            if (nl - prev > 0) // Skip empty strings
                add_entry(prev);
            *nl = '\0';         // Terminate entry
            s = nl + 1;         // Skip to first byte after \0
            prev = s;           // This is the start of the 'previous' record
        }
        else {
            *nl = ',';          // Replace \n with comma
            s = nl + 1;         // Move pointer forward (optimization). 
            if (*s == '\n')
                *(s - 1) = '\0';// Don't add trailing comma
        }
    }

    if (prev < s)
        add_entry(prev);        // Don't forget last entry
}

static int entrycmp(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const struct entry *p1 = v1, *p2 = v2;

    return strcmp(p1->val, p2->val);
}

// Sort the entries so the pointers point to a sorted list of strings.
static inline void sort_entries(void)
{
    qsort(g_entries, g_entrysize, sizeof *g_entries, entrycmp);
}

// We keep things really simple and allocate one unique entry for each
// entry. That's the worst case anyway and then we don't have to test
// for reallocation.
static inline void setup_unique_table(void)
{
    size_t cb = sizeof *g_unique * g_entrysize;
    if ((g_unique = malloc(cb)) == NULL)
        exit(__LINE__);

    g_uniquesize = 0;
    g_uniquecapacity = g_entrysize;
}

static inline void add_unique(char *s)
{
    g_unique[g_uniquesize].val = s;
    g_unique[g_uniquesize].count = 1;
    g_uniquesize++;
}

// Now count and skip duplicate entries. 
// How? Just iterate over the entries table and find duplicates.
// For each duplicate, increment count. For each non-dup,
// add a new entry.
static inline void find_unique_entries(void)
{
    char *last = g_entries[0].val;
    add_unique(last);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < g_entrysize; i++) {
        if (strcmp(g_entries[i].val, last) == 0) {
            g_unique[g_uniquesize - 1].count++; // Inc last added\'s count 
        }
        else {
            last = g_entries[i].val;
            add_unique(last);
        }
    }
}

static inline void print_unique_entries(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g_uniquesize; i++)
        printf("%zu %s\n", g_unique[i].count, g_unique[i].val);
}

static inline void print_entries(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g_entrysize; i++)
        printf("%s\n", g_entries[i].val);
}

static int uniquecmp(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const struct uniq *p1 = v1, *p2 = v2;
    return (int)p2->count - (int)p1->count;
}

static inline void sort_unique_entries(void)
{
    qsort(g_unique, g_uniquesize, sizeof *g_unique, uniquecmp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(__LINE__);
    }

    mapfile(argv[1]);
    setup_entry_table();
    convert_to_entries();

    if (g_entrysize == 0) // no entries in file.
        exit(0);

    sort_entries();
    setup_unique_table();
    find_unique_entries();
    sort_unique_entries();

    if (0) print_entries();
    if (1) print_unique_entries();

    // cleanup
    free(g_entries);
    free(g_unique);
    munmap(g_baseaddr, g_filesize);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a C program, other alternatives exist as well. Here's an awk snippet which folds lines. Not perfect, but should get you started :)

```
$cat foo.awk
// {
    if (NF == 0)
        printf("\n");
    else
        printf("%s ", $0);
}
$ awk -f foo.awk < lots_of_data | sort | uniq -c | sort -nk1
```

The last statement will take "forever", which is why a C program may be a good alternative. It depends mostly on how often you need to run the commands.

Comment: You've been misinformed. awk scripts are usually faster than C programs for manipulating text and a C program would certainly not be faster than that shell pipeline and would take significant effort to implement given that the "sort"s are only necessary if your data is too large to all fit in memory at one time and so you'd have to write some pageing code to handle it like sort does.

Comment: @EdMorton
"awk scripts are usually faster than C programs for manipulating text "

You're saying that awk, a program written in C, somehow is faster than other programs written in C. That doesn't make much sense to me. 

The opposite makes a lot more sense, that a custom C program is faster than a general purpose language built on C, since the custom C program can use specialized algorithms since it knows more about the problem at hand than any general purpose language can possibly do.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm saying. The reason is that the C code that awk uses for text manipulation is highly optimized for common text manipulation operations and so outperforms the code that people write by hand, more than making up for differences in interpreted vs compiled code. If you don't believe me, try writing a C program to do what [the awk script I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986378/1745001) does more efficiently.

Comment: @edmorton Hold my beer :) I can do that, at least try, if you provide the test data or a script to generate the test data on a Linux host, as well as the test criteria up front (No moving goal posts...)

Comment: @EdMorton: Excellent. I love a good challenge :) To avoid misunderstandings, the timings should include all parts of OP's task, not just the awk part, agree? The reason I mention this, is that that's the reason I wrote upthread that a C program may be a better solution.

Comment: The first awk script I wrote does everything including sorting the output numerically so there is nothing except "the awk part" - THAT is the challenge, to write a C program that does the same but more efficiently.

Comment: Actually - @creed, can you post your 10m record input file somewhere and provide a link to it?

Comment: Gimme a second to gather such sample.

Comment: @EdMorton . Ack, and a valid point you make, even if there was a slight misunderstanding on the terms. Not to worry, I still accept the challenge. (Need something todo to take my mind off this dreadful toothache)

Comment: @EdMorton i can compress to different format. it was compressed with xz.

Comment: The file you have posted is separated by TWO `\n` between header blocks.

Comment: sorry, correcting with sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta'   New file with only one space: https://expirebox.com/download/81e1b58414c55cdc13a180d7dbb94067.html  , removed previous files for clarity.

Comment: @EdMorton I've written a C program which produces the same output as your AWK script, modulu some corner cases due to weird test data, I assume. The results on my old box? The AWK script uses about 5.2 seconds to process the rows. The C program? Sorry to say(not sorry:) that the C program is twice as fast. How do I post the source code?

Comment: Yup that's the ratio I got too on cygwin on my laptop - for this particular problem the awk program ran in 5 seconds and the C in about 2.5. I suspect the differences in the output are just in the order the tools chooses to output lines with identical counts - after I run both outputs through UNIX `sort` they are identical. Interestingly whether I sorted within awk or not make almost no difference to the execution time but adding a pipe to sort made the whole script take 20 secs instead of 5.

Comment: So I was wrong about a C program not being faster than the shell pipeline with the `sorts` (I assume buffering is the issue but idk...) but I stand by the statement that awk scripts are usually faster than C programs for manipulating text and even in the cases like this where a C program does turn out to be a bit faster it's certainly not worth writing 221 complex lines of C instead of 8 trivial lines of awk to possibly improve execution time by a couple of seconds. Thanks for providing the C code to test with!

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for playing, and for keeping such a professional and rational attitude. Much appreciated! The Awk solution is of course better than the C solution in most cases, but C is always faster. Not to write, but to execute. That doesn't make C the better choice, far from it. Speaking of speed, I woke up with a couple of ideas to make the C program a little faster, and will now check if this pans out.

Comment: @BjornA. I'm sorry to harp on it but C isn't generally faster than awk. I used GNU awk for this test as it's what I have on hand but Mawk is faster than GNU awk and available if performance is the primary goal. See for example https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/ where manipulating 1G of data took 1m06s with mawk vs 1m35s with C. I haven't personally come across a case where gawk wasn't fast enough and so I had to use mawk instead but THAT would be my performance improvement path if necessary, not C.

Comment: In case you wondered why I'm fairly adamant about this - I've been programming in C for over 30 years and awk for about 20 years and one example of my experience with this area is in my previous job we had software construction tools written in awk that converted several hundred thousand lines of code written in a domain-specific-language to C before the C compiler ran and our management team wanted the overall build process to run faster so they had us rewrite the conversion tools in C. Of course, there was no performance improvement - just a ton more code and plenty of debugging!

Comment: @EdMorton No worries, Ed. I have no problems with people feeling strongly about an issue, as long as they're willing to argue for their view, like you do very well. I still disagree, though ;)

Comment: Ditto and I suspected you might :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory (10M records, in your sample about 80 chars per record, 800MB, and if you're counting them, I assume a lot of duplicates) you could hash the records to memory and count while hashing:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""; OFS=","} 
{
    b=""                       # reset buffer b
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)         # for every header element in record
        b=b (b==""?"":OFS) $i  # buffer them and comma separate
    a[b]++                     # hash to a, counting
}
END {                          # in the end
    for(i in a)                # go thru the a hash
        print a[i] " " i}      # print counts and records
' file
1 Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
1 cookie,Cache-Control,referer,x-fb-sim-hni,Host,Accept,user-agent,x-fb-net-sid,x-fb-net-hni,X-Purpose,accept-encoding,x-fb-http-engine,Connection
1 User-Agent,Host,Connection,Accept-Encoding
1 Host,Connection,Accept,From,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding,X-Forwarded-For
```

Output order is random due to the nature of `i in a` so order the output afterwards as pleases.

**Edit**:

As @dawg kindly pointed out in the comments, `$1=$1` is enough to rebuild the record to comma-separated form:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""; OFS=","} 
{
    $1=$1                      # rebuild the record
    a[$0]++                    # hash $0 to a, counting
}
END {                          # in the end
    for(i in a)                # go thru the a hash
        print a[i] " " i}      # print counts and records
' file
```

Comment: You do not need to manually put into a CSV format. With `OFS` set to `','`, just do `$1=$1; a[$0]++` Look at Ed Morton's...